# How to filter a Meteor Collection by elements in an array data field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm currently designing a system similar to Gmail's labeling system. In my "Messages" Collection, I have a field that holds an array containing the IDs of the labels associated with the current Message, which are held in a different Collection. The JSON data for some Message looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "W9uCWJCqx8ozsbX6t",
    "name" : "Issue",
    // ... some more data fields ...
    "labels" : [ "R2syna2dnRdf4TDfC", "FHrjNbAT7Da2dRR5F" ] // IDs of labels in an array
}
```

How would I use something along the lines of the `.find()` method to search for all Messages that contain a certain label ID in its `labels` field?

Comment: you can do something like this `db.messages.find( { labels: "<insertlabelid>" } )`

Comment: @SagarReddy Thanks, that worked! I didn't realize `find()` would search inside the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` operator of MongoDB.

Example query :

```
Messages.find({labels : {$elemMatch : {$eq: id}}});
```

More use cases can be found in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)